# pygame window continuously crashing

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

white=(255,255,255)
black=(0,0,0)
red=(255,0,0)
green=(0,255,0)
blue=(0,0,255)

gameDisplay=pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
gameDisplay.fill(black)

Displayer=pygame.PixelArray(gameDisplay)

pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, blue,(100,200),(300,450),5)
pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, (400,400,50,25))
pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, white,(150,150,),75)
```

I used the code to make some shapes but I am unable to export it.
The pygame window always stops responding. How would I stop this behaviour?

Comment: What is `Displayer=pygame.PixelArray(gameDisplay)` for? You don't need this line of code. A `PixelArray` locks the surface.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line:

> ```py
> Displayer=pygame.PixelArray(gameDisplay)
> ```

This will lock the `gameDisplay` and the following drawing operations will fail. You don't need that line of code at all. [`pygame.PixelArray`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pixelarray.html) locks the surface:

> During its lifetime, the PixelArray locks the surface, thus you explicitly have to close() it once its not used any more and the surface should perform operations in the same scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `Displayer=pygame.PixelArray(gameDisplay)`

And also you will need to write `pygame.display.flip()`

This will actually display all the drawings on the screen.

The last  thing you need is a while loop that runs until the program ends to make sure you are drawing  the shapes on every frame:

```
pygame.init()

white=(255,255,255)
black=(0,0,0)
red=(255,0,0)
green=(0,255,0)
blue=(0,0,255)

gameDisplay=pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
gameDisplay.fill(black)

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    gameDisplay.fill((255, 255, 255))

    pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, blue,(100,200),(300,450),5)
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, (400,400,50,25))
    pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, white,(150,150,),75)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

This is the most common way to do it, you check we didn't close the window, and then draw on every frame each shape, then use `pygame.display.flip()` to actually display everything.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Very likely the contributor didn't show  us his the full code. I am very sure that he has an application loop.